# Font resize to large font causes unreadable text

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-size

I want to set my font-size to 700%, but this causes the text to be unreadable.

the font-size of the body is set to:

```
small
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Unreadable]

[image: Everything fine]

Html:

```
<div class="splash-page main-body" [@routerTransition]="">
  <div class="thisClassNameIsToLong">
    <span class="whyAreYouInspectingMe">
    Stijn Aerts
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css (Sass):

```
html,body
  height: 100%
  font-size: small

.wrapper
  min-height: 100%
  position: relative

.main-body
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 100%

.splash-page
  background: #1565C0

  .thisClassNameIsToLong
    margin: auto

    .whyAreYouInspectingMe
      font-family: "Pacifico"
      //font-family: "'Times New Roman', Times, serif"
      font-size: 600%
      white-space: nowrap
      color: white

.arrow-wrapper
  width: 100%
  margin: auto
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  text-align: center

.arrow-box
  margin: auto
  color: white
  text-align: center

  i
    color: white
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    margin: 20px
    margin-bottom: 0
    padding: 20px
    cursor: pointer
```

Maybe it is worth mentioning I'm using Angular v2 and Materializecss.

EDIT: I'm also using Font-Awesome and when I exclude it, everything seems fine. Very weird.

Comment: why don't use `vh' , 'em', 'rem' or `vmin'?

Comment: They cause the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by Chrome's disable web security mode.

So if you have this problem, run Chrome without:

```
--disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```